# Resolution/size of string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a mini program that basically takes a vector of strings (from user input) and displays or prints out an increased & decreased resolution (size) of it.

It would increase or decrease each character of each string by 4.
Example: if the string is "abcdef" then increased resolution would be "aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff"

I was having trouble writing the code. I don't want it to not only loop through the vector of strings but I want it to read the characters of each string in the vector and produce the resolution results.

Is there anyway of doing that? I keep getting these conversion errors from the compiler

```
void asci_art::bigresol(vector<string>art)
{
   cout << "Increased Resolution of your artwork" <<endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < art.size(); i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < art[i].size(); j++)
       {
          cout << art[j] + art[j] + art[j] + art[j] << endl;
        }
     }
   }
```

btw I wrote this function in a class.

In this case, I'm writing a function that increases the resolution. I assume decreasing resolution would be the same idea.

Comment: If you pass the vector<string>art by value (as in the example), it will call the copy constructor for vector and make a copy of the vector, which is quite wasteful.  Instead, pass it by pointer (vector<string>* part) or const reference (const vector<string>& rart).

Comment: Why does the title say "C" ?

Comment: @PaulR i meant C++ so ignore that

Comment: It's a good idea to hit the `edit` link above and fix typos such as this.

Comment: It's also a good idea to leave the tags in the tags section, not the title.

Comment: If your string is "abcdef", then each character can't occupy a position in the vector, it really only contains one string. Unless you mean to say that `a` is in position 0, `b` is in position 1, etc.

Comment: @0A0D well thats what i want to do. i want to access each character of the string

Comment: So why are you using a vector? Is the intention to have one string per position? Meaning `abcdef` in pos 0, `fedcba` in pos 1, etc ?

Comment: @0A0D yes pretty much. I designed the program in a way that the user would supposedly create an "artwork" through lines of strings.

Comment: Tip: what is the type of the variable `art[j]`?

Comment: By the way, you should at least use `unsigned`, if not `std::vector<std::string>::size_type` or `std::string::size_type` when iterating through containers and `std::string` without iterators. The preferred way in C++03 is `for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = art.begin(); it != art.end(); ++it)`

Answer (score 2):

You're concatenating strings instead of concatenating characters. Form the string you need from each character instead of each string:

```
std::cout << std::string(4, art[i][j]); //put the newline in the outer loop
```

You should also consider having your parameter be a `const std::vector<std::string> &` so as to avoid unnecessary copies when calling the function. Also consider using the nice range-for syntax, introduced in C++11:

```
for (const auto &str : art) {
    for (auto c : str) {
        std::cout <<  std::string(4, c);
    }

    std::cout << '\n'; //put a newline in between each transformed string
}
```

Comment: I dont have C++11. i think i have an older compiler

Comment: You think? Do `gcc -ver`

Comment: @user2188311, You don't need it to do this, but it sure makes it look nicer (and so does Boost a lot in C++98/C++03). You can try enabling the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` options. Also, did you mean to print a newline after each string instead of each group of characters?

Comment: @chris yes after each string

Comment: @user2188311, I included that in my rewritten answer. It took me longer to notice that you were adding strings, not characters, though it looks like you meant to add characters.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops - I misinterpreted.

I think this is what you want, in your style:

```
void asci_art::bigresol(vector<string> art)
{
    cout << "Increased Resolution of your artwork" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < art.size(); i++)
    {
        line = art[i]
        for(int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++)
                cout << line[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting. so why should I put j < 4? What does that do exactly in the iteration? I don't quite understand

Comment: This prints each string four times.

Comment: No, this prints `abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef`

Comment: It does this: 'if the string is "abcdef" then increased resolution would be "aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff"'.

Comment: @danf, [No it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5c25b7dfd7305759522d2c2a806c1e66-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59)

Comment: Yup I read the problem as a vector<char> input.

Comment: That looks better. That's what I read the first time I read your answer when it was posted.

Comment: You really need something like this https://ideone.com/u4JKLR ... just saw your edit nvm

Comment: In your defense, the question wasn't phrased well

Comment: I, myself, thought the `operator+`s were being applied to `char`s for how long before I realized they were `std::string`s.

Comment: @0A0D the question was clear. i even provided an example to show what I'm saying

Comment: thank you everyone for the help though

Comment: @chris, Oh I see. There should even be another loop that prints duplicates of each line to increase resolution vertically. Four nested loops!

Comment: Wait, vertically, too? @user2188311, Is that right?

Comment: @user2188311: it isn't clear at all and now we are potentially talking about printing vertically?!